# sequelize validation: allow only one item to be true for single property

Tags: sequelize.js

```
export default function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const OrderAddress = sequelize.define('OrderAddress', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    is_default: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    receiver_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    phone_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    address_detail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    postcode: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }
});
```

My `orderAddress` model looks like above and I want to have a validation to allow only one item to have `is_default` set to `true`.

so,

```
const address = {
  is_default: true, // default one
}
const address2 = {
  is_default: true // no you can't!
}
```

Should I make `is_default` field `unique: true` or add some custom `validation` for this model?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple ways to achieve this.

1. Sequelize provides an option for [hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/hooks.html) which are triggered on particular events in a query lifecycle.
   Using a `beforeCreate` or `afterValidate` hook you can do a fetch and find if there are any records with `is_default` as `true`, just throw an error.
2. Add a [trigger](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php) on DB layer, which checks if there any any existing rows with `is_default`. Such triggers could be added and managed by sequelize migrations

Comment: For #2 I think using a unique index via Sequelize would be better than a trigger.

Comment: Yeah, for bulkCreate, you would need to add a hook `beforeBulkCreate`
Unique index won't work if there are more than two addresses for a particular order

Answer (score 0):

You could either add a unique index on the `order_id` (or whatever your relational field is) and `is_defualt` (first example), or you can refactor it a bit to set the `default_address` on the `Order` instead of setting it on the `OrderAddress` (2nd example)

**first option, add unique index**

```js
// ...
  indexes: [
    {
      fields: ['is_default', 'order_id'], // or whatever your relational field is
      unique: true,
    },
  ],
// ...
```

**second option, check at the Order level**

Assuming that `OrderAddress` belongs to something like an `Order` model, you can also add the validation here for efficiency. Since you want to know which address is the default, and only allow one, add a field called `Order.default_address` and set the values to an enum of either "address" or "address2", indicating which to should be used - naturally only one can be set and not both.

On the `Order` model you can then add a `beforeValidate` hook that checks to see if the field set as the "default" contains an ID for an `OrderAddress`.

```js
export default function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
    // your fields
    default_address: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM(),
      values: ['address', 'address2'],
      allowNull: false,
      // defaultValue: 'address',
  },
  {
    hooks: {
      beforeValidate: function(instance) {
        switch (instance.default_address) {
          case 'address':
          case 'address2': {
            // check to see if address_id or address2_id is set, as needed
            if (!instance[instance.default_address + '_id') { // or + 'Id' if you use camel case
              return Sequelize.Promise.reject(
                new Error(`Default "${instance.default_address}" not set`)
              );
            }
          }
          default: {
            return Sequelize.Promise.reject(
              new Error('You must set a default address')
            );
          }
        }  
      },
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The #1 option would break if there are more than 2 address available for a single order.  
With changes to the schema #2 would surly work

Comment: True about #1, I couldn't tell from the question.